# Django Custom Management: trouble in writing command to populate data

Tags: django, django-orm

I am new to django management commands! I am trying to write a commands to populate author...

My `models.py` is:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    summery =  models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and i am tried to write a command but i failed..

this is my `blog/management/commands/populate_author.py` below:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from blog.models import Author, Book

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Populate author'


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Author.objects.create()
        Author.save()
```

Can anyone please help me to make it happen?

Comment: What issues have you encountered with your approach?

Comment: No, issue, I just tried, i am confused where to start... I am very new in management commands, not getting how to start it

Comment: When you run "python manage.py" you should get a list of all available management commands. Yours should appear in a section named "blog", does it?

Comment: I tried python manage.py pupulate_author once i write code in pupulat_author.py but that code not worked

Comment: What do you mean by it not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes, it throws me an error: TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: `Model.objects.create()` will already save the object to the database, you do not need to call `save()`. FYI, you should call `save()` on an instance not on the class itself

Comment: The saved author is return by create: `author = Author.objects.create(<kwargs go here>)`

Comment: now it is fires me these error: e3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: blog_author.email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196110/discussion-between-iain-shelvington-and-mamuncode).

Comment: ok, come to chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create an `Author` without giving any data for the fields.  If you've managed to create one `Author` with a blank value for the required `email` field, then the next `Author` you try to create will have a blank `email` field and that is what causes the non-unique error.  Do this to create an `Author`:

```
Author.objects.create(name='Author Name', email='authoremail@domain.com')
```